# Pass data from Angular controller to MVC action on submit button

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create array in angular controller as below (example).

```
contacts: [{
   id: 1,
   name: "Ben",
   age: 28
}]
```

I would like to pass this array to MVC action on form submit.
Can anyone please let me know how to do it. 
Example will be more helpful.

Comment: You need to add some extra detail to your request. It is not very clear what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

If you have created this array which you want pass to the backend in a controller, that means in angular code, it doesn't make a lot of sense to send it on form submit, I would rather make an AJAX call using $http object.

However if you mean that you want to add some data, do something like that:

```
<script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
     var contacts = [{
                  id: 1,
                  name: "Ben",
                  age: 28
                }];
      $scope.submit = function() {
        $http.post("/route/to/your/controller/action", 
                   {
                         contacts: contacts
                   }).success(function(data, status) {
               // handle result
         })
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply. I agree with you. Ajax call is more appropriate.
But after posting data to MVC action, I would like to display view.
After calling $http.post,I could not able to render view hence I am looking for form submit. Please suggest option to render view after post data.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `$http` service to make an ajax call to send your data. If you want to redirect to a a new view, you may use the `$window` object for that.

```
var myCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $window) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.saveItem = function () {

        var contacts = [{ id: 1, name: "Ben", age: 28 }];

        $http.post("../Contacts/Save", contacts)
        .then(function (res) {
            var r = res.data;           
            if (r.status === "success") {
                $window.location.href = r.newUrl;
            }
            else {
                alert("Some error");
            }
        });
    };


};
myCtrl.inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
```

Assuming you are calling this from a page like

```
<div  ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myCtrlas vm">
    <button type="button" ng-click="vm.saveItem()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Make sure to return a JSON object which has a `success` and `newUrl` properties , which our client code is going to look for,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<UserViewModel> users)
{
   // to do  :Do something with the posted data.
    var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
    var t =url.Action("Success", "Contacts");
    var res = new { status = "success", newUrl = t };
    return Json(res);
}
```

And the UserViewModel will look like

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int Age { set; get; }
}
```

This is a working solution. But you might consider moving your server call code to an angular [data service](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services) and inject that to your controller instead of using `$http` directly in your controller.

Take a look at the [angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). Following that will make your angular code clean and efficient,